# Phonegap - Issue with Android Virtual Keyboard and Textfield Visibility

Tags: html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile, android-keypad

I am creating a Phonegap application for android using JQuery Mobile.  I have a particular page where the user needs to register and send out a form.  However, I am encountering a very weird issue with the textfields at the bottom of the page.  When the android virtual keyboard pops open, it is hiding my textfields and the user would not be able to see what he/she is inputting.

Can anyone suggest what I can do so that the textfield that has focus is always visible?  Also, is there a way so that when the user clicks next/go from the android virtual keyboard the focus would go to the next textfield in line?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure if it might help to do some process on the scroll - ie scroll the text field upwards..  Any suggestions?

Comment: I could fix it by modifying `overflow` property in css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Just add the following to the manifest and it works :) :

activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

Comment: Still I'm getting the same problem and also I have used the iScroll to my page. What should I do?